# Extra vowel before inverted "je"

Tags: prononciation, interrogative, inversion, liaisons

Somehow I didn't notice the following phenomenon till recently.

Normal inversion:

> Je dors.
>
> Dors-je ?

New phenomenon for me:

> Je parle des trois mousquetaires.
>
> **Parlé-je** des trois mousquetaires ?

I have a few questions about this.

1) Is there a name for this phenomenon so I can research it?

2) It would seem that this is kind of a reverse liaison: whereas liaison is the surfacing of a consonant to break up two vowels, this is the insertion of a vowel to break up a cluster of consonants that would be hard to pronounce consecutively, such as [ʀlʒ]. Is this right, or is there another reason?

3) Is there, then, a specific set of rules for which consonant clusters or which words this can affect? For example, which of these collocations would be affected after inversion?

> J'achète
>
> Je bouge
>
> Je soulage (a mild tongue twister after inversion si la règle s'applique !)
>
> Je pèse
>
> J'abaisse
>
> Je compte
>
> Je sonne

As you can see, my working hypothesis is that only -er verbs are affected, since -ir verbs always have an -i to break up the cluster and I'm having trouble thinking of -re verbs that won't either end in a vowel or a single consonant (e.g. *mords-je*, which is not hard to pronounce). But this would be further complicated if, for example, you can think of any structure in which a verb in the subjunctive would be inverted!

4) For words in which this is done, is it *always* done or is it affected by factors of register, dialect, generation, etc.? Or is it in free variation? (I'm partly trying to figure out why I haven't encountered it.)

5) Is it true, as it seems, that context is all that can distinguish this from "Parlais-je"?

Merci !

Comment: Isn't it an accent _grave_ rather than _aiguë_: _parlè-je_? It sounds like one.

Comment: Also - another tidbit: we don't use these very often, and I predict they will disappear soon. They sound a bit _pedantic_ already. For sure, we don't use them in conversation, we tend to fall back on _est-ce que_ already to avoid this construction.

Comment: Ce lien confirme qu'on a tendance à éviter ces tournures: https://books.google.com/books?id=-mUTAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA5-PR4&lpg=RA5-PR4&dq=tournure+parl%C3%A9-je&source=bl&ots=5MV8f4cM9x&sig=R8A_tYGzjvd6DrZmpr2GjSao9r4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSg93p3rTSAhWni1QKHQ0wDiMQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=tournure%20parl%C3%A9-je&f=false

Comment: We are having a good laugh here with _mords-je dans la pomme?_, _mordè-je dans la pomme?_ and other improbable variations thereof, that none of us would ever have thought about or used ;-)

Comment: Non, c'est bien un accent aigu. Sinon ça sonnerait comme *parlais-je*.

Comment: @Frank "Est-ce que" peut s'employer dans une question, mais quand l'inversion ne concerne pas une question, je ne vois pas en quoi *est-ce que* pourrait intervenir. Par ailleurs mordre ne se terminant pas par un e muet au présent de l'indicatif ("je mords"), cet exemple est mal choisi. Il ne s'agit pas dans la question posée de l'inversion du *je* en général (pour ça voir par exemple [ici](http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/INTERRIVE.htm)) mais de la transformation du [ə] en [ɛ] dans les cas d'inversion du sujet avec *je* quand le verbe se termine par un *e* muet.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps - mais ça se prononce plus comme un accent grave à mon oreille. Voir _noté abusivement é_ dans le Grevisse cité par Laure.

Comment: @Frank Je ne sais pas ce qu'on peut entendre par "tournure interrogative", c'est certes une inversion sujet-verbe, mais qui ne sert pas forcément à poser une question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La raison de ce phénomène est phonétique. En français c'est la dernière syllabe de la phrase ou du groupe de mots qui est accentuée. Quand un mot se termine par un *e* muet c'est l'avant-dernière syllabe qui est accentuée.  Dans le cas d'inversion du sujet avec *je*, le sujet lui-même ne pouvant pas être accentué, l'accent est reporté sur l'avant dernière syllabe.

Ce qui est possible avec, par exemple :

> **Suis**-je vraiment aussi en retard ?
>
> Me voici, **dis**-je en poussant la porte.

(syllabes accentuées en gras)

ne l'est plus quand le verbe se termine par un *e* muet (ce qui est le cas au présent de l'indicatif pour tous les verbes en *-er* et quelques verbes en *-ir*, et de tous les verbes, sauf *être*, aux temps simples du subjonctif) car le français n'admet pas l'accentuation sur l'antépénultième syllabe.

Dans le groupe de mot «  <strike>chante-je</strike> » on ne peut faire porter l'accent tonique ni sur *je* (jamais accentué au contraire des autres pronoms sujets) ni sur la syllabe qui précède parce qu'elle se termine par un *e* muet :

> <strike>La la la la la, chante-je gaiement.</strike>

devient :

> La la la la la, chanté-je gaiement.

De façon à rendre le groupe de mot prononçable selon les règles d'accentuation du français on met un accent aigu sur le *e* final du verbe.

À noter qu'il s'agit bien d'un accent aigu mais qu'il se prononce [ɛ].

Voici comment Grevisse présente le phonème (*Le Bon Usage*, dixième édition ; Les parties du discours, le verbe, § 638, A) :

> Le pronom *je* postposé étant atone, fait en quelque sorte, corps avec le verbe. or comme la langue n'admet, dans aucun cas, que l'accent d'intensité frappe l'antépénultième syllabe, on a dû, dans la combinaison du verbe et du pronom *je*, accentuer la pénultième, c'est à dire la syllabe finale du verbe : de là le changement de l'*e* muet en *e* ouvert (noté abusivement é).

Ce phénomène se trouve dans tous les cas d'inversion du sujet, pas seulement donc dans les tournures interrogatives, mais aussi dans les propositions incises ou les propositions qui expriment un souhait.

> Nous faisons la guerre, m'écrié-je (Ch. de Gaulle, Mémoires de guerre)
>
> Puissé-je en finir avec cette histoire !
>
> Je tiendrai jusqu'au bout, dussé-je en mourir.

À remarquer aussi (et Grevisse le signale) que ce *é* est parfois remplacé par *-ai*

> Dussai-je cent fois y périr (J.J. Rousseau, *Les Confessions*)

---

> -ir verbs always have an -i to break up the cluster.

The -ir verbs that end with *e* in the 1st person present tense are:
*assaillir, couvrir, cueillir, défaillir, offrir, ouvrir, souffrir, tressaillir*.

> [Mais, en m'offrant à vous, que vous offré-je ?](https://books.google.fr/books?id=dwM2TCcBQVsC&pg=PA337&lpg=PA337&dq=%22offr%C3%A9-je%22&source=bl&ots=6F1DvsDkJM&sig=hBjjEDcKVebUP-6K52yImFAGJVc&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiho831orXSAhVMlxoKHe6NDacQ6AEIOzAI#v=onepage&q=%22offr%C3%A9-je%22&f=false) (Denis-Xavier Clément *Exercices de l'âme* - 1827)
>
> [Si je souffrais de ma réclusion je ne l'avouerai jamais, certes ; mais en réalité, en souffré-je ?](https://books.google.fr/books?id=gFSq6JFWX5oC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22souffr%C3%A9-je%22&source=bl&ots=J-3OHvPmJR&sig=aXm08vIJhjz0XyUIKEVN7V1aQK8&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJkLv1obXSAhXM1xoKHaRLAAEQ6AEIPDAH#v=onepage&q=%22souffr%C3%A9-je%22&f=false) (Albert Grunberg, *Journal d'un coiffeur juif à Paris*, sous l'Occupation, 2001).

Sur ce dernier exemple on pourrait se demander si l'auteur a bien voulu employer le présent, car dans cette phrase l'imparfait serait aussi possible, donc « en souffrais-je ».

---

Suite aux commentaires sur la différence graphie/phonie du  *é* qui se prononce [ɛ], j'ai continué à réfléchir et j'ai consulté l'orthographe rectifiée de 1990 -  et donc depuis 1990 on peut aussi écrire ce *e* final, qui apparaît dans les inversions avec le pronom *je*,  conformément à sa prononciation  [ɛ], c'est à dire avec accent grave : *è*. Plus dans l'article *[Grammaire française:La postposition du sujet](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Grammaire_fran%C3%A7aise:La_postposition_du_sujet_%C2%AB_je_%C2%BB)* du wiktionary. Avec, au passage de nombreux exemples pour illustrer cette inversion.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. In particular, it's very helpful to see that this is, despite an unfamiliar orthography, just another way of realizing an *e muet* that has ended up receiving stress — like "acheter" gaining an accent grave in "j'achète". The fact that this "euphonie" is pronounced [ɛ] s'accorde particulièrement bien avec ce phénomène. And good point about the irregular -ir verbs; no doubt there are irregular ones of any ending that will be affected or unaffected, so I suppose the rule should be formulated based on the presence of the *e muet* rather than the ending.

Comment: It'll take me a bit of time to get my head around "dussé-je" and "dussai-je" (I need more practice with the subj. impf. forms!). I wonder how Rousseau would have pronounced "dussai-je" in particular. Finally, can you confirm then that all the examples I gave under my third question would experience this phenomenon?

Comment: @LukeSawczak They could theoretically all experience the phenomenon but in reality although inversion of the subject with 1st person singular is more frequent with *-er* verbs than other verbs, it's never met with some verbs.   [This](http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/INTERRIVE.htm) only deals with  the inversion in questions but what is said applies to other cases, and some verbs would probably never be used / needed in interpolated clauses or wish clauses.

Comment: Merci ! It's certainly true that it's difficult to imagine contexts in which one is unsure whether one is doing some of these verbs. ;) The suggestion that some inversions would be systematically replaced by "est-ce que" formulations, rather than it simply depending on formality, is very interesting, though.

Comment: @LukeSawczak "Est-ce que "would only work if inversion is in a question, which I think is not the most frequent use.

Comment: True. (Just noting the claim "On évitera *Finis-je?* ... au profit de *Est-ce que je finis?*" in that link and wondering how systematic that is!)

Comment: @LukeSawczak - I would say it is systematic when speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more comments:

1. I couldn't find a name for that phenomenon, besides *euphonie*.
2. I think the only reason for this is *euphonie*, to avoid a difficult to pronounce combination of consonants.
3. Grammatically you could form *achetè-je*, *pesè-je*, but those are IMHO never used, and instead we fall back on *est-ce que j'achète*, *est-ce que je pèse* ... but ...
4. ... it is rarely done in practice, at least when speaking. The register would be *pedantic*, certainly when speaking. Also you cannot always use this construction in a meaningful way. Who would say *dors-je?* (now)? Also, if the inverted form is in an interrogative sentence, we would use *est-ce que* much more readily, certainly in conversation, and avoid this inversion.
5. I would say it is fairly indistinguishable, and we think of the *imparfait* way before we realize it could possibly be a present with an inverted "*-je*".
6. For the cases where the vowel used is *é*, although it's written with an *é*, it's definitely not pronounced like an *é*.
7. We don't quite learn to form those expressions systematically in school. We encounter a few at some point probably in literature, but I would say that is about it. We can recognize them, but we might be hard pressed to make one.
8. Some of these expressions are tied to a subjunctive (without the usual *que* we associate to the subjunctive?):

   > Puissé-je en finir avec cette histoire !
   >
   > Je tiendrai jusqu'au bout, dussé-je en mourir.
   >
   > Eussé-je ...

   So, I have a follow-up hypothesis that these expressions (or at least those tied to a subjunctive) could function more and more these days as ready-made formulas, in limited number, that we still see sometimes in print, but wouldn't use normally when talking, or even at all.

Comment: Along with the imperfect subjunctive, this euphonious *é* is still quite common in written and even refined spoken French forms *dussé-je* and *eussé-je*.

Comment: @jlliagre - do you have data to support "quite common"?

Comment: Many thanks for the notes on usage!

Comment: For the improbable "Dors-je ?", perhaps it could be an indirect way to wonder if one is dreaming. :)

Comment: Tous les verbes aux temps simples du subjonctif se termine par un *e*muet. « Il faut que je puisse en finir !  » → « Puissé-je en finir.  ». (présent du subjonctif). « ... que je dusse en mourir.  » est un imparfait du subjonctif.  « J'eusse » est un imparfait du subjonctif. « Eussé-je continué à vivre ainsi, pauvre et délaissée ? »

Comment: Very interesting additions. Agreed that the possibility that certain forms were fixed historically and should not be incorporated into the general rules of a language's grammar is always a live question! As far as my original question goes, though, I guess that the existence of inverted subjunctives in general shows that I'll have to watch out for this phenomenon with *e muets* resulting from those cases and know how to interpret them when I see them... even if I'll be doing my best to avoid having to use *Eussé-je* myself. :)

Comment: Donc ces expressions seraient calquées sur un subjonctif? Mais pas toujours: _parlé-je_ pourrait être dérivé d'un indicatif. Aussi, comme nous utilisons de moins en moins les subjonctifs, cela pourrait renforcer l'hypothèse que ces tournures - au moins celles liées à un subjonctif - sont en train de devenir des formules figées - et qui ont déjà plus ou moins disparues à l'oral.

Comment: Elle ne sont pas « calquées » sur un subjonctif, ce sont des subjonctifs dans le cas de dussé-je, eussé-je, etc. « m'écrié-je » **est** un présent... Ce ne sont pas des expressions, ce sont des verbes.

Comment: Oui - mais le verbe dans l'expression est _dussé_ et _je_ est un pronom. L'expression est composée d'un pronom et d'un verbe. Mais peu importe. Aussi, quel est le statut du _que_ habituel dans les subjonctifs? Où est-t'il passé dans _dussé-je_?

Comment: L'inversion permet ici de s'abstenir du *que*, comme avec *je crus de mon devoir de le soigner, tout anglais **fût-il*** (Micheline Lachance) ou *Il répondait à contre-cœur, parce qu'il savait que Nadine adorait parler d'elle mais que tout jugement, **fût-il** bienveillant la blessait* (Simone de Beauvoir). On peut aussi noter l'absence de *que* dans « **Soient** deux variables x et y… »

Answer (score 0):

I would take issue with *dors-je* as the inversion for *je dors*.  The one I would use, jocularly, if I ever felt such an inversion was called for is *dormé-je* pronounced /dɔrmɛ:ʒ/.

The whole thing is the subject of a special chapter in Ménage's Observations sur la langue française dating back to 1675 but that remains relevant. [https://books.google.de/books?id=Z4-1NbejwPAC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=perds-je+perdé-je+ménage&source=bl&ots=VqQIZrslRM&sig=ACfU3U1c12HGPoFUlviJoabcdWUfr4nByg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9r_ef4ZPjAhWLQUEAHfhYBCAQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=perds-je%20perdé-je%20ménage&f=false](https://books.google.de/books?id=Z4-1NbejwPAC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=perds-je+perd%C3%A9-je+m%C3%A9nage&source=bl&ots=VqQIZrslRM&sig=ACfU3U1c12HGPoFUlviJoabcdWUfr4nByg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9r_ef4ZPjAhWLQUEAHfhYBCAQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=perds-je%20perd%C3%A9-je%20m%C3%A9nage&f=false)

Here's what Pierre Richelet (1626-1698) had to say :

**JE**.  Ce pronom, mis après le verbe, marque l'interrogation, et alors si la première personne finit par un *e* féminin [/ə/] , il se change en *e* masculin [/ɛ/] ; ainsi on dit *pensé-je à cela?* et non *pense-je?*

Que si la première personne du verbe n'est pas un *e* féminin [/ə/], elle ne se change en *e* masculin [/ɛ/] que quand la prononciation du *je* après la première personne est rude, ou fait équivoque.  C'est pourquoi on ne peut point dire *sens-je?*, *dors-je?*, *sers-je?*, *romps-je*? mais *senté-je?*, *dormé-je?*, *servé-je?*, *rompé-je?*  Et au contraire on dit *dois-je?*, *fais-je?*, *suis-je?* à cause que cette prononciation n'est pas vicieuse et ne fait point équivoque.

**Ceux-même qui parlent bien et qui ont de la délicatesse pour la langue condamnent ces façons de parler, *senté-je*, *mangé-je*, *dormé-je*, *rompé-je*, etc.  Ils diront plutôt *est-ce que je mange*, *que je dors*, etc.**

It's difficult see what is meant by *prononciation rude* but it's clear that all these forms are felt to be problematic.  The bit of advice at the end that I put in bold is one, I believe, everybody should heed.

I'll conclude with an intuition about the way in which the system works: in case of inversion with *je*, the /ɛ:ʒ/ tag is tacked onto the stem of the verb /ʃɑ̃t ɛ:ʒ/, /dɔrm ɛ:ʒ/, /sɛrv ɛ:ʒ, /rɔ̃p ɛ:ʒ/.

The stem is not the necessarily the one we derive from the infinitive but rather the one we get from the plural form of the present, which explains *écrivé-je* /ekriv ɛ:ʒ/, *cousé-je* /kuz ɛ:ʒ/ or *finissé-je* /finis ɛ:ʒ/.  *Suis-je*, *dois-je*, *dis-je*, which are the among the only ones that are commonly used, are in fact exceptional in their form.

Here are some examples of their use:

- Aussi metté-je toujours quelques chiffons rouges dans ma parure (BALZAC, La Peau de chagrin)
- «Dans le cas d'une crise suscitée par les Soviets», écrivé-je à Kennedy ... (Ch. de GAULLE, Mémoires d'espoir)
- Ai-je cousu, cousé-je, coudrai-je dans du cuir ? (COLETTE, Le Fanal bleu)
- Aussi finissé-je cette lettre en…