# When to insert a "t" in inversion?

Tags: grammaire, inversion

I noticed that the inversion of many phrases has a **t** inserted in between, like *y a-**t**-il* (is there), *a-**t**-on* (have we), or even *y sera-**t**-il* (will there be), but not always.

Quand faut-il ajouter un **t** à l'inversion? (je sais qu'il n'y a pas un **t** en <s>*devrais-**t**-je*</s>)

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/956/quand-%c3%a9crire-ce-t-sorti-des-m%c3%a9andres-de-la-phon%c3%a9tique

Answer (score 4):

Le "t" est principalement utilisé pour faciliter la prononciation .

Dans les exemples "y a-t-il" et "y sera-t-il" seraient difficilement prononçables sans ce "t". On enchaînerait 2 voyelles d'affilées "y sera-il".
Cela est dû au fait que le sujet de la question est à la 3ème personne du singulier "Il / Elle/ On". "Que mange-t-on ce soir ?"

Le problème ne se pose pas pour certains verbe dont la 3ème personne du singulier se termine par un "t" ou un "d" "Que doi**t**-il faire ?" "Que ven**d**-elle ?"  (car ici le "d" se prononce "t", comme si le verbe s'écrivait "Que vent-elle ?")

La 3ème personne du pluriel l'évite également, car en général, le verbe se finit par un "t", il n'y a donc pas besoin de l'ajouter une nouvelle fois "Que fon**t**-ils ?" "Y seron**t**-ils ?"

Les autres pronoms commençant par une consonne (**j**e, **t**u, **n**ous, **v**ous), ils n'ont pas besoin de lettre supplémentaire pour faciliter la prononciation.
"Que dois-**j**e faire ?" "Que fais-**t**u ?" "Où allons-**n**ous ?" "Que vendez-**v**ous ?"

Pour résumer : si une inversion implique les pronoms "Il / Elle / On" et que le verbe ne finit ni par un "t" ni un "d", il faut ajouter un t entre le verbe et le pronom.

Comment: Is there a list of verbs whose *il* form ends in neither T nor D, and is not a vowel?

Comment: I don't think that this kind of list exists. But for examples, all verbs from the 1st group (which end by -er : aimer, donner, marcher, ...; always end with an 'e' "Il aime", "elle donne", "on marche") will need this additionnal 't'. But for the 2nd and 3rd group, there's no such rules, you'll have to know each verbs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a form of [liaison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)): a consonant is inserted to breaks up [hiatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(linguistics)), a sequence of vowels.<sup>1</sup>

Specifically, this is a *liaison obligatoire*, because the verb and subject pronoun form a [tight bond](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitique#Langues_romanes).

**Hence, you insert ⟨t⟩ if the verb ends with a vowel and the pronoun begins with one.**

As far as the spelling goes, this situation only arises with the pronouns *il*, *elle*, and *on*.

> A-**t**-on déjà payé ?
>
> Fera-**t**-il la tâche avant jeudi ?

Note that in this inversion, a final *e muet* is considered non-silent,<sup>2</sup> so you insert ⟨t⟩.

> Regarde-**t**-elle la télé ?

In terms of writing, that's all you need to know. However, listening to the actual sounds, notice that the last sound you hear in many verbs is a vowel. So you don't *write* an extra ⟨t⟩, but you do *pronounce* the last consonant, usually /t/.

> Veu**t**-il toutes les pâtes ?

That also affects *ils* and *elles*: they start with a vowel and the verbs end with a vowel sound, despite being spelled ⟨nt⟩. That's true even in present tense, because of the *e muet* phenomenon above.

> Venden**t**-ils du café ?
>
> Voudraien**t**-elles déjeuner chez toi ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Meanwhile, four pronouns begin with consonants: *je*, *tu*, *nous*, *vous*. The last two have conjugations that end in vowels: *-ons*, *-ez*. But *je* and *tu* have conjugations that end in consonants. This results in the opposite problem: overfull consonant clusters. That question is discussed in [this thread](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24876/extra-vowel-before-inverted-je).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> In practice, that doesn't mean you'll actually hear a clear *re-gar-deu-tel*. A deletion rule can still follow.</sub>

Comment: Slightly OT: Does *-ent* remain silent in *vendent-ils* or *voudraient-elles*? Or does *-en-* remain silent while *t* makes a sound? In other words, does *vendent-ils* sound like *vende til* or *venden til*?

Comment: @iBug It sounds like *vende-t-il*. But much like my note on *regarde-t-elle*, in practice you might not hear two distinct consonants, maybe an unreleased /d/ and an audible /t/. For other tenses, like *voudraient-elles*, you'll always hear a clear *voudrai-tel* since the vowel before the *nt* isn't a schwa.